# After how long the web page session/cookies end when authenticated using Azure AD Authentication?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-ad-msal, azure-authentication

Net MVC 4.7.2 application. This application is using Azure Identity platform for user authentication. When user is on company's network and sign in to app, as it seem the session doesn't look to end. Probably because of Sigle Sign On seamless authentication.  So that is okay when user user in company's network and session go for long even when user logout or stay idle.

The question is what if user is not in company's network and sign in to the application, I want to figure out the exact minutes that for how long the session/or authentication cookies are set to expire when web app is in idle state?

Answer (score 0):

> **The **`IdleTimeout`** determines how much time the session is idle before the contents in cache are abandoned.**

- The **`IdleTimeout`**  doesn't depend on the cookie expiration.
- The expiration of session cookies varies browser to browser.
- The **`Timeout`** property can be set in `Web.config` file for the application like below:

```json
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <sessionState
      mode="InProc"
      cookieless="true"
      timeout="30" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Please **note** that, the session/or authentication cookies are set to expire when web app is in idle state is 20 minutes by default as mentioned in this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-6.0#session-options) like below:

[image]

- The **`IdleTimeout`** can be set up to **`525,600`** minutes (1 year) and it applies to Net MVC 4.7.2 version too.
- The default frequency for [**user-sign**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/howto-conditional-access-session-lifetime#user-sign-in-frequency) is **`90`** days.

*You can setup session cookie in Azure Active directory, please **refer** this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/howto-conditional-access-session-lifetime#policy-1-sign-in-frequency-control).*

Comment: thanks for the reply.  What do you mean by this statement "The default frequency for user-sign is 90 days.".  2nd thing is the app that I am using, as I mentioned   it is using AD Authentication , so when I on corporate account it takes care of the session seamlessly, but when I am not on the corporate account. I do need to signin because session cookies expires at some time, and I am not able to see that logic and the idle time when session cookies expire and user need to sign in.  I see web config file doesn't have any logic for it.